# Spring security mutiple login process doesn't work it supposed to do

Tags: java, spring, spring-security

I'm suffering for multiple login processing.

I've searched a lot about it and none of answers out there are working.

I wrote two login processing one for admin and the other one for normal user.

And also wrote each success and failure handlers but the handlers are always working with the last one in `@order(2)` configuration even though I request to `/admin`.

My problems are:

1. I can login but the success handler is always triggered as the last one in `@order(2)`.
2. The failure handler is triggered but as the last one as well regardless what URL I request and it throws 404 error (I can see it goes on proper controller during debugging). Maybe tiles doesn't work on failure process?

Here is my security config:

```java
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
@AllArgsConstructor
public class SecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {
    private UsersServiceImpl usersService;

    @Bean
    public PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder() {
        return new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
    }

    @Override
    public void configure(WebSecurity web) throws Exception {
        web.ignoring().antMatchers(
                "/css/**",
                "/js/**",
                "/img/**",
                "/font/**",
                "/html/**",
                "/jusoPopup",
                "favicon.ico"
        );
    }

    @Configuration
    @Order(1)
    @NoArgsConstructor
    public static class AdminConfigurationAdapter extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {
        @Override
        protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
            http
                .antMatcher("/admin/**")
                .authorizeRequests()
                    .anyRequest().hasRole("ADMIN")
                    .and()
                .formLogin()
                    .loginPage("/admin/login")
                    .defaultSuccessUrl("/admin")
                    .failureHandler(adminFailureHandler())
                    .permitAll()
                    .and()
                .logout()
                    .logoutRequestMatcher(new AntPathRequestMatcher("/logout"))
                    .logoutSuccessUrl("/")
                    .invalidateHttpSession(true)
                    .and()
                .csrf().disable();
        }

        @Bean
        public AuthenticationSuccessHandler adminSuccessHandler() {
            return new CustomLoginSuccessHandler("/admin");
        }

        @Bean
        public AuthenticationFailureHandler adminFailureHandler() {
            return new CustomLoginFailureHandler("/admin/login?error=true");
        }
    }

    @Configuration
    @Order(2)
    @NoArgsConstructor
    public static class NormalConfigurationAdapter extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {
        @Override
        protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
            http
                .authorizeRequests()
                    .antMatchers("/Ticketing/**", "/**/write").hasRole("MEMBER")
                    .anyRequest().permitAll()
                    .and()
                .formLogin()
                    .loginPage("/login")
                    .successHandler(successHandler())
                    .failureHandler(failureHandler())
                    .permitAll()
                    .and()
                .logout()
                    .logoutRequestMatcher(new AntPathRequestMatcher("/logout"))
                    .logoutSuccessUrl("/")
                    .invalidateHttpSession(true)
                    .and()
                .headers()
                    .frameOptions().sameOrigin()
                    .and()
                .csrf().disable();
        }

        @Bean
        public AuthenticationSuccessHandler successHandler() {
            return new CustomLoginSuccessHandler("/");
        }

        @Bean
        public AuthenticationFailureHandler failureHandler() {
            return new CustomLoginFailureHandler("/login?error=true");
        }
    }   

    @Override
    public void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        auth.userDetailsService(usersService).passwordEncoder(passwordEncoder());
    }    
}

class CustomLoginSuccessHandler extends SavedRequestAwareAuthenticationSuccessHandler {
    public CustomLoginSuccessHandler(String defaultTargetUrl) {
        setDefaultTargetUrl(defaultTargetUrl);
    }

    @Override
    public void onAuthenticationSuccess(
            HttpServletRequest request,
            HttpServletResponse response,
            Authentication authentication
    ) throws ServletException, IOException {
        HttpSession session = request.getSession();
        if (session != null) {
            String redirectUrl = (String) session.getAttribute("prevPage");
            if (redirectUrl != null) {
                session.removeAttribute("prevPage");
                getRedirectStrategy().sendRedirect(request, response, redirectUrl);
            } else {
                super.onAuthenticationSuccess(request, response, authentication);
            }
        } else {
            super.onAuthenticationSuccess(request, response, authentication);
        }
    }
}

@Getter
@Setter
@AllArgsConstructor
class CustomLoginFailureHandler implements AuthenticationFailureHandler {
    private String defaultFailureUrl;

    @Override
    public void onAuthenticationFailure(
            HttpServletRequest request,
            HttpServletResponse response,
            AuthenticationException exception
    ) throws IOException, ServletException {
        String errorMessage = "some error message";

        request.setAttribute("errorMessage", errorMessage);

        request.getRequestDispatcher(defaultFailureUrl).forward(request, response);
    }
}
```

It's hard to find proper working well multiple login processing resource out there if you guys know the good resource about it please let me know.

I hope it's my code error so that I don't have to change the application structure.

I read some Baeldung guide and spring security documents Here is my edited configuration :

```java
@EnableWebSecurity
public class SecurityConfig{

    @NoArgsConstructor
    @Configuration
    @Order(1)
    public static class AdminConfigurationAdapter extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {
        @Override
        protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
            http
                    .antMatcher("/admin/**")
                    .authorizeRequests().anyRequest().hasRole("ADMIN")
                    .and()
                    .formLogin()
                    .loginPage("/admin/login")
                    .defaultSuccessUrl("/admin")
                    .failureHandler(adminFailureHandler())
                    .permitAll()
                    .and()
                    .logout()
                    .logoutRequestMatcher(new AntPathRequestMatcher("/logout"))
                    .logoutSuccessUrl("/")
                    .invalidateHttpSession(true)
                    .and()
                    .csrf().disable();
        }

        @Bean
        public AuthenticationEntryPoint authenticationEntryPoint(){
            BasicAuthenticationEntryPoint entryPoint =
                    new BasicAuthenticationEntryPoint();
            entryPoint.setRealmName("admin realm");
            return entryPoint;
        }

        @Bean
        public AuthenticationFailureHandler adminFailureHandler() {
            return new CustomLoginFailureHandler("/admin/login");
        }
    }

    @AllArgsConstructor
    @Configuration
    public static class NormalConfigurationAdapter extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {
        private UsersServiceImpl usersService;

        @Bean
        public PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder() {
            return new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
        }

        @Override
        public void configure(WebSecurity web) {
            web.ignoring().antMatchers(
                    "/css/**",
                    "/js/**",
                    "/img/**",
                    "/font/**",
                    "/html/**",
                    "/jusoPopup",
                    "favicon.ico"
            );
        }

        @Override
        protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
            http
                    .authorizeRequests()
                    .antMatchers("/Ticketing/**", "**/write")
                    .hasRole("MEMBER")
                    .anyRequest().permitAll()
                    .and()
                    .formLogin()
                    .loginPage("/login")
                    .successHandler(successHandler())
                    .failureHandler(failureHandler())
                    .permitAll()
                    .and()
                    .logout()
                    .logoutRequestMatcher(new AntPathRequestMatcher("/logout"))
                    .logoutSuccessUrl("/")
                    .invalidateHttpSession(true)
                    .and()
                    .headers().frameOptions().sameOrigin()
                    .and()
                    .csrf().disable();
        }

        @Override
        public void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
            auth.userDetailsService(usersService).passwordEncoder(passwordEncoder());
        }

        @Bean
        public AuthenticationSuccessHandler successHandler() {
            return new CustomLoginSuccessHandler("/");
        }

        @Bean
        public AuthenticationFailureHandler failureHandler() {
            return new CustomLoginFailureHandler("/login");
        }
    }

}

class CustomLoginSuccessHandler extends SavedRequestAwareAuthenticationSuccessHandler {
    public CustomLoginSuccessHandler(String defaultTargetUrl) {
        setDefaultTargetUrl(defaultTargetUrl);
    }

    @Override
    public void onAuthenticationSuccess(
            HttpServletRequest request,
            HttpServletResponse response,
            Authentication authentication
    ) throws ServletException, IOException {
        HttpSession session = request.getSession();
        if (session != null) {
            String redirectUrl = (String) session.getAttribute("prevPage");
            if (redirectUrl != null) {
                session.removeAttribute("prevPage");
                getRedirectStrategy().sendRedirect(request, response, redirectUrl);
            } else {
                super.onAuthenticationSuccess(request, response, authentication);
            }
        } else {
            super.onAuthenticationSuccess(request, response, authentication);
        }
    }
}

@Getter
@Setter
@AllArgsConstructor
class CustomLoginFailureHandler implements AuthenticationFailureHandler {
    private String defaultFailureUrl;

    @Override
    public void onAuthenticationFailure(
            HttpServletRequest request,
            HttpServletResponse response,
            AuthenticationException exception
    ) throws IOException, ServletException {
        String errorMessage = "Error";

        request.setAttribute("errorMessage", errorMessage);

        request.getRequestDispatcher(defaultFailureUrl).forward(request, response);
    }
}
```

It looks more organized than before i guess but still has the same problem... also read about AuthenticationEntryPoint but not sure it's fit in my case

Comment: I guess you need to add entry points. See https://www.baeldung.com/spring-security-multiple-entry-points

Comment: @Ritesh First of all, thank you for your reply. Could you explain me why i need to add entry points? As you can see the above code i wrote there are already success and failure handlers for each configuration.

Comment: My guess is that the default entry point [LoginUrlAuthenticationEntryPoint](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/5.3.0.RELEASE/api/org/springframework/security/web/authentication/LoginUrlAuthenticationEntryPoint.html) is shared. This entry point  redirects an unauthenticated request to the login form.  Since you have 2 login forms, you would need 2 entry points.

Comment: @Ritesh I'm not sure if it is correct way to use entry point but i appended entry point at the end of configure with exceptionHandling() each but i think nothing is changed.

Comment: See the section 3.2 of the link where 2 different entry points are configured for 2 patterns ("/user/private/**" and "/user/general/**") and 2 login forms ("/userLogin" and "/userLoginWithWarning").

Comment: Yeah i think i did it correctly and it seems that it just connect proper login form for certain url.